# Totally ordered sets with special operations for precursor or postcursor or max or min

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Is there a name for a totally ordered set with an operation to get the precursor (or postcursor) of a given element in the set?

Is there a name for a totally ordered set with an operation to get the maximum (or minimum) element in the set?

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly a totally ordered set in which every nonempty subset *has* a minimum element is called a well-ordered set.  The name for such an operation is usually just $\min$.  Totally ordered sets with both a minimum and a maximum for nonempty subsets are called *Dedekind finite*.

Comment: And they really *are* finite.